# How to tell what layout is being used within a Nuxt.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have two Nuxt.js layouts, default.vue and secondary.vue. There's the same footer.vue component that is being used in both of these layouts. I'd like to change some CSS classes inside of the footer.vue component based upon which layout the component is being used in. How Does one know what layout is being used from within a component nested in Nuxt.js layout?

Comment: You could pass down a `type` property or something depending on what component is using footer. So in `default.vue` when you render `footer.vue` give it a prop type called 'default'. Same with `secondary.vue`. And then in `footer.vue` check prop type and change css there.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I tried something like that with vuex. However, how  do you create a lifestyle hook when a layout is loaded? mounted() and created() do not work in layouts.

Comment: The lifecycle methods belong in the logic of the component, so of course you can't use them in the layout. That should be irrelevant though. Just pass down a property to `footer.vue` ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following:

```
this.$nuxt.$data.layoutName
```

Which will return the name of the layout file used.

Comment: It looks like using $nuxt.$data causes problems in SSR mode.

Comment: @JonathanArias Hmm, you're absolutely right. It seems as if the change was made sometime after nuxt 2.8 or so. I'm not sure my answer is relevant now 2 years later. If you find a solution, feel free to answer this question or suggest an edit!

Comment: The only thing I've found is that $nuxt.layoutName works too, but it causes the same error.